# prove $A=B \iff A \times A = B \times B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Tried to prove it. wasn't 100% sure I did everything correctly so I would appreciate a lot your advice. this is what I've done:[image]

Comment: Your proof looks good.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically fine.  But you don't even need to prove anything for part (a).  If $A= B$ then you can substitute $B$ in for $A$ in any expression and the two expressions will be equal.  $A$ and $B$ are exactly the same, so all you're doing is calling $A$ by a different name.  Also, I would try to write in complete, grammatical sentences.

> Suppose $a \in A$.  **Then** $(a,a) \in A \times A$, so ...